# Как передать значение select option в БД?

Tags: php, sql, mysql

Собственно, в чём проблема... Вот форма....

```
<form method=post action=add_event.php id=testForm>
    <b>Соус</b><br />
        <select neme=inv>
        <option value=yes>Да</option>
        <option value=no>Нет</option>
    </select>
    <input type=submit value=Сохранить class=noresize submit />
</form>
```

Вот как она обрабатывается:

```
$inv = (isset($_POST['inv'])) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['inv']) : '';

$error = false;
$errort = '';

if (strlen($head) < 2)
{
    $error = true;
    $errort .= 'Вы не вписали заголовок';
}
if (!$error)
{
    $query = "INSERT
                INTO `bd`
                SET
                    `inv`='{$inv}',
                    `salt`='{$salt}'";

    $sql = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    print 'Информация добавлена';
}
else
{
    print 'Возникли следующие ошибки' . $errort;
}
```

select option не принимается и не отображается в базе данных, после добавления. При этом появляется надпись: "Информация добавлена". Дайте совет, пожалуйста.

Comment: Валидатор в помощь. http://validator.w3.org/

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка в коде. Попробуйте так:

```
<form method=post action=add_event.php id=testForm>
    <select name=inv>
      <option value=yes>Да</option>
      <option value=no>Нет</option>
    </select>
    <input type=submit value=Сохранить class=noresize submit>
</form>
```

Вот как она обрабатывается:

```
$inv = (isset($_REQUEST['inv'])) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['inv']) : '';

$error = false;
$errort = '';

if (strlen($head) < 2)
{
    $error = true;
    $errort .= 'Вы не вписали заголовок';
}
if (!$error)
{
    $query = "INSERT
                INTO `bd`
                SET
                    `inv`='{$inv}',
                    `salt`='{$salt}'";

    $sql = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    print 'Информация добавлена';
}
else
{
    print 'Возникли следующие ошибки' . $errort;
}
```

Comment: во первых... ошибка не NEME а NAME. _POST заменили на _REQUEST

Comment: $_POST - $_REQUEST некритично, в форме то ясно сказано что это POST, IMHO

Comment: Почему SET??? Может:

    INSERT INTO `bd` (inv, salt) VALUES('$inv', '$salt');

?

Answer (score 1):

не живите в прошлом веке, используйте PDO - удобство, автоматическая фильтрация данных + еще куча вкусностей

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass);

$inv = $_POST['inv'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO bd (inv) VALUES (:inv)";
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array(':inv' => $inv));
```